# Как прокрутить scrollview к указанной кнопке?

Tags: android, java

Имеется **scrollview** в нем таблица кнопок. Как мне прокрутить **scrollview** к кнопке, которая располагается вне видимой области **scrollview**?

Ex.

```
ScrollView  scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
....//тут мы каким  то образом надобавляли кнопок в scrollView
....
//и есть кнопка button, которая уже находится в scrollView;
```

Comment: в хмлки все сложить... =)

Comment: не вариант, обавление должно быть данамическим, кнопок больше 100 штук

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сделать `scrollTo()` до кнопки, причем это надо делать через `ScrollView.post()` - то есть послать оконной системе сообщение, что скроллинг будет после отображения контента.

```
PostScroller ps = new PostScroller(myScrollView, 0, pos); //pos - позиция кнопки
myScrollView.post(ps);

class PostScroller implements Runnable
{
    private View view;
    private int x, y;

    PostScroller(View view, int x, int y)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        view.scrollTo(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: это понятно, а как мне позицию кнопки получить, загвоздка вся в этом

Answer (score -1):

```
int top = view.getTop();
scrollView.scrollTo(0, top);
```

Comment: Поясните, что это даст в решении проблемы?